# glmer intercept predicted probability and SE

Tags: lme4-nlme, lsmeans

I have the following model:

```
mod = glmer(outcome ~ 1 + (1|ID), family = binomial(link="logit"), data = df)
```

OR

```
mod2 = glmer(outcome ~ Condition + (Condition |ID), family = binomial(link="logit"), data = df)
```

I am interested in obtaining the predicted probability for the intercept, with its associated SE.

Using `lsmeans` I can get these values for models with predictors, e.g.:

```
lsmeans(mod2, ~Condition ,infer = c(TRUE,TRUE), type = "response")
```

However, I have not found a way to get this information for the intercept; `lsmeans` seems to require a predictor variable. These do not work:

```
lsmeans(mod, ~1,infer = c(TRUE,TRUE), type = "response")    
lsmeans(mod, ~.,infer = c(TRUE,TRUE), type = "response")    
lsmeans(mod,infer = c(TRUE,TRUE), type = "response")
```

Comment: what if you code an intercept, as predictor (i.e, vector of one's)?

Comment: I decided this could be a useful feature, so I added it, and the next update of **lsmeans** will support a spec of the form `~1` or `"1"` with no need to create an intercept column. It may be a month or so before I upload this to CRAN.

Comment: @user137451 the updated package is now available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, to make this question "solved":
Code an intercept (i.e, vector of one's) and include it as predictor.